# java Integer.parseInt() acting weird

Tags: java, server, udp, client, communication

So I've been working on a server-client program where the client sends the server a string, the server splits that string to perform certain calculations.

//message sample

```
18011d5651,0,348,1649520496736,5,0:1010,1
```

then the message is stored in a string called msg

when I try to run the following line on the server side:

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(msg.split(",")[4]);
```

it returns an error as follows

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at test.test1.main(test1.java:54)
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds) ```
````

Comment: Can't recreate. Tried
        `String msg = "18011d5651,0,348,1649520496736,5,0:1010,1;int d = Integer.parseInt(msg.split(",")[4]);System.out.println(d);` and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Possibly there are some hidden/non-printable characters in that string. Try to log `msg.split(",")[4].length()`.

Comment: len is : 835 :) which is extremely strange..

Answer (score 2):

the problem was solved with

```
.replaceAll("\0", "")
```

I was sending the data from a client to a proxy to a server, so in the proxy, it was reading 1000 bytes, and of which are being appended to the last element "5" then the part that the proxy adds was appended (,0:1010,1) so there were 834 nulls. using the line above I replaced all the nulls in the message in the proxy before forwarding it to the server, then added the proxy part then sent it to the server and the processing was successful.

another way to tackle it is by removing the nulls from it on the server-side, but if the server buffer was 1000 bytes we'll have an issue too, cuz the proxy appended part wouldn't be delivered. I didn't realize why that was happening until I made the buffer in the server 1100 bytes.

the solution given that the buffer in the server is 1100 bytes is as follows

```
String msg = "18011d5651,0,348,1649520496736,5,0:1010,1".replaceAll("\0", "");
int d = Integer.parseInt(msg.split(",")[4]); 
> d = 5
> d.length() = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So as per your self-answer, the problem was that you had lots of unexpected NUL characters (`'\000'`) in the message string you were processing.

Your solution was to just remove all of the NUK's with `replaceAll`. This is (IMO) suboptimal, and possibly incorrect.  There are two problems:

1. You are still sending messages from your server that are bloated with meaningless NUL characters.  That *costs* network bandwidth.  It also *costs* CPU time on the client side, directly because of the extra data copying, the `replaceAll`, etc, and indirectly because you will be generating more garbage.
2. Depending on how your server is implemented, it is possible that it is recycling its output buffer between successive messages without fully zeroing it.  If that is the case, and the messages don't always have the same length, then it is possible that there will **occasionally** be garbage characters in the string that are not NUL characters.

Rather than trying to fix this on the client side, I think you need to fix the server so that it doesn't send messages with garbage characters in them.

---

Per your followup comments, the problem is on the receiving end.  You are receiving the data in datagrams, and the junk is due to receiving into a byte array that is larger than the datagram.

In that case, you have a bug in your receiving code.  The `DatagramPacket` class has a `getLength` method that returns the number of bytes of data actually received.  You should use that value (not the byte array size) where you are converting the bytes to a `String`; e.g.

```
String msg = new String(datagram.getData(), 0,
                        datagram.getLength(), charset);
```

Comment: My implementation is relatively primitive. It's based on the built-in DatagramPacket, and DatagramSocket classes. The issue here is not that the null characters are being sent from the server or vice versa. the issue is the the buffer I'm using to receive the messages is too big, and all its contents are initialized to '\0' (null). So the message that we receive from the other end is 10 characters long for instance, but we store it in a byte array that has a size of 100. when we attempt to read the last element, we read the nulls with it.

Comment: there is for sure a much better solution than using the (replaceAll("\0", "")) out there, but it worked for my purposes, and my implementation (keeping in mind that it's not a production server or anything of that sort), so I guess that makes it less suboptimal for my particular case?

Comment: Well ... when you receive a datagram into a buffer, the API tells you how many bytes were received.  You should capture that value ... and use it to create the string comprising only the byte values that you actually received.

Comment: The point is that when you answer your own question on StackOverflow, what you are actually doing is providing an answer for >>other people<< to read.  While your solution works for you ('cos you are prototyping, etc) it is not good advice for other people who *maybe* are writing production code.  It is important that we don't give people *bad advice*.   As it turns out from your comments, `replaceAll` is clearly the wrong fix for an apparently straight-forward bug.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is that server uses different charset enconding. You can try converting the charset to UTF-8:

```
    int d = Integer.parseInt(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(msg.split(",")[4])));
```

You should import StringUtils:

```
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
```

Comment: For what it is worth, most character encodings use the same codes for the digits '0' through '9' as UTF-8 does.  So using a different character encoding is unlikely to make a difference here, even if your guess at the correct encoding is correct.